# Visual Studio 2015: source control explorer won't download files/projects

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I am working in VS2015 update 2. Our TFS is the latest version/build (Microsoft sent people out to help set it up)

Up until today, checking out files was a simple matter of clicking on them and it pulls/gets latest version.

Now, it is saying:

> "All files are up to date. No files were updated because the
>   requested file versions were previously downlaoded. To enforce an
>   update, use the 'get specific version' command with the 'overwrite
>   all...' option selected"

[image: Screenshot]

This would be fine... if I actually had local files... but I don't and it is still grayed out in Source Control Explorer.

I tried getting a specific version like it suggested, no dice. I checked both checkboxes and tried different versions, changesets, dates to no avail.

Comment: `Specific Version` with `Overwrite all` checked?

Comment: So you do not have local version and trying to get the version/copy from server, if am not wrong..

Comment: correct I cannot get files from TFS

Comment: Did you map the server location with your local folder?

Comment: the main  root is mapped, of course. any other time I just 'get latest' and it creates any subfolders and puts the files in. But now it isn't. Never have had to map each individual folder as it is all under one workspace

Comment: No that's not an option to do.. You dont need to map individual folder... Not sure what's going on unless I see it..

Comment: I have just heard that my specific group might not have specific permission to this specific branch for some specific reason in Specificland... I'll post back when I hear a definite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a permission spasm going on with our TFS box. someone turned off inheritance and manually set everything everywhere for some reason.

Problem solved after cleaning up all conflicting permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tf permission command](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/tfvc/permission-command) to list all permission info of the folder with all account such as `tf permission /server:<servername> <folder path in TFS>`

*Note: To use the permission command, you must have the Manipulate security settings permission set to Allow for the folders being modified, be a member of the Team Foundation Administrators security group, or be a system administrator on the local computer (Windows Administrator security group).*